# Sencha Touch Post to Node.js Error

Tags: node.js, extjs, sencha-touch-2, node.js-domains

I am trying get a json with Sencha Touch from a cross-domain node.js

my node.js code:

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Request handler random was called.");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    var otherArray = ["item1", "item2"];
    var otherObject = { item1: "item1val", item2: "item2val" };
    var json = JSON.stringify({ 
        anObject: otherObject, 
        anArray: otherArray, 
        another: "item"
    });
    res.end(json);
});
```

here the code works fine: http://still-stream-9036.herokuapp.com/login

but when i try to get with sencha touch i got:

```
(failed)
Invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

// Enables CORS

```
var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-   Length, X-Requested-With');

// intercept OPTIONS method
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
  res.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
}
};


// enable CORS!
app.use(enableCORS);
//--------------
```

Font:
stackoverflow.com/questions/21236954/sencha-touch-post-to-node-js-error